# Can Spring-AMQP connect and process messages from AMQP1.0 brokers

Tags: amqp, spring-amqp, qpid

Can spring-amqp communicate with AMQP 1.0 brokers, keeping the fact that spring does not support AMQP 1.0 version ?

I get to know about QPID Proton API which I am planning to use but I would prefer going with Spring provided solution to connect AMQP1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring AMQP is based on the AMQP 0.9 protocol which is RabbitMQ implementation.

We investigated QPID and Proton and end up with the solution that `spring-jms` can simply be used to communicate with their AMQP 1.0 client implementation.

> I am considering closing this with the recommendation of using spring-jms over qpid-jms to talk to AMQP 1.0 brokers.

More context is here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-662

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I have committed a small implementation in Github based on your inputs. Anyone looking for AMQP 1.0 connectivity using Spring-JMS or Spring Integration can run the sample once. And its just a matter of creating Qpid ConnectionFactory. https://github.com/zaidahmd/spring-boot-amqp-1-0

Comment: The repo is empty though

Comment: My Apologies. I missed to commit after uploading. Its available now.